# What is the maximal number of iterations in the e1071 svm() function?

Tags: r, svm, e1071

I know that there is a hard coded number of maximal iterations in the e1071 svm() function, but can someone tell me how high this number is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SVM implementation of `e1071` is an R interface to the C++ `libsvm` library developed by Chih-Jen Lin. The best way to figure out what iteration limit is used is to look at the source code [here](https://github.com/cjlin1/libsvm/blob/master/svm.cpp). Line 561 defines the iteration limit:

```
int max_iter = max(10000000, l>INT_MAX/100 ? INT_MAX : 100*l);
```

The value of `INT_MAX` varies from compiler to compiler, so it would be fair to say that the practical iteration limit is in most cases **10000000**.

Comment: Thank you. I allready looked there, but my C++ skills are 
not existent.

Comment: I extracted `e1071` from https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/e1071_1.7-13.tar.gz . I modified this line (line 567) in `e1071/src/svm.cpp`. I used the Rtools installer at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/files/rtools43-5550-5548.exe . Because I was using RStudio, in the console of RStudio I ran `install.packages("C:/Users/Tom/Documents/e1071", repos = NULL, type = "source")`. How does this command cause `e1071/src/e1071.dll` to be built?